# flow of checkout page field - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms

Last two days I have spent to set default value in checkout page. Please anyone give suggestion about **what is flow behind checkout page field?**

for example take one field city, give the full flow list about city field.I am not expecting whole process just hints of flows enough.